# Can not update doctrine-orm-module 3 in Laminas project

Tags: doctrine-orm, composer-php, laminas

I am trying to update Doctrine Module in my Laminas project to version 3 using Composer but I am getting errors.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 3.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 3.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 3.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 3.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 3.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/doctrine-module 2.1.10
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-orm-module ^3.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-orm-module[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2,
3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-module 2.1.10
    - doctrine/doctrine-orm-module 3.0.0 requires doctrine/doctrine-module ^4.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-module[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-module[4.0.0, 2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-module[4.0.1, 2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-module[4.0.2, 2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-module[4.0.3, 2.1.10].
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-module (locked at 2.1.10) -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-module[2.1.10].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any ideas as to why doctrine-orm-module is not installing. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing doctrine-orm-module but with no luck.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "kryten/direct_sites",
    "description": "Direct Sites",
    "license": "",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf3",
        "Ecommerce"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.3",
        "laminas/laminas-component-installer": "^2.1",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc": "^3.1",
        "laminas/laminas-filter": "^2.9",
        "laminas/laminas-crypt": "^3.3",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc-plugin-flashmessenger": "^1.1",
        "laminas/laminas-i18n": "^2.9",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^2.2",
        "krytenuk/refresh-redirect": "^2.0",
        "krytenuk/logger": "^2.0",
        "krytenuk/recaptchav2": "^2.0",
        "krytenuk/mailchimp": "^0.2.0",
        "laminas/laminas-serializer": "^2.9",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc-i18n": "^1.1",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
        "laminas/laminas-permissions-acl": "^2.7",
        "laminas/laminas-navigation": "^2.9",
        "laminas/laminas-cache": "^2.8",
        "ocramius/package-versions": "^1.4",
        "laminas/laminas-feed": "^2.12",
        "symfony/filesystem": "^4.2",
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": "^1.0",
        "krytenuk/messenger": "^1.1",
        "laminas/laminas-file": "^2.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Auth\\": "module/Auth/src/",
            "Admin\\": "module/Admin/src/",
            "Author\\": "module/Author/src/",
            "User\\": "module/User/src/"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the command `composer require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` and I get the response `Using version ^3.0 for doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` followed by the message above.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Please share more details, like the given `composer.json` and whatever command you are running that yields the given output

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up the `vendor/` directory as it might contain the too old version of `doctrine/doctrine-module` installed previously.

As another solution, I suggest you execute `composer update` and see if there are any errors.

Usually, in such cases the most common problem is that `composer require ...` does not upgrade the existing packages.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. No luck, still getting same error. Update works with no errors but not updating doctrine module.